# Allocate multi-dimensional arrays with the GIL released

Tags: cython

I need to release the GIL to work with paralllel threads. With the GIL released we can interact with memoryviews, but we can not create them because it relies on the garbage collector of the Python interpreter. The code I am writing is fairly simple, so managing the memory manually should not be a big problem.

So far I see two options for allocating arrays dynamically in conjunction with `prange`. The first option is to momentarily regain the GIL just to create a memoryview, and then immediately release it. I'm not sure if this is  even allowed, and how much this degrades performance.

Another option is to declare a double pointer, and allocate memory to each row in a for loop. And later free the memory in a similar fashion, using methods like these:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef int** allocate_array(int N, int M) nogil:
    cdef int **arr = <int**>malloc(N * sizeof(int))
    cdef int i
    for i in range(N):
        arr[i]=<int*>malloc(M * sizeof(int))
    return arr

def void free_array(int** arr, int N) nogil:
    cdef int i
    for i in range(N):
        free(arr[i])
    free(arr)
```

This seems like quite a bit of code for something so common. Furthermore I actually need 3 and 4 dimensional arrays as well, making it even worse.

Is there really no simpler way to do this? I have read all the relevant Cython documentation, as well as the Cython book by Smith, but didn't find any relevant information.

Comment: "momentarily regain the GIL" is allowed, in a `with gil:` block. How much it degrades performance depends on a lot of things, and is something you have to measure. `**` arrays are almost always the wrong choice - use a 1D array and some "shape" data like numpy does

Comment: How can I create a 1D array with "shape" data (without the GIL)? Everytime translating A[i,j] to say A[i*N+j] can be annoying, especially with even more than 2 dimensions. And I guess `**` arrays are bad because they are not contiguous?

Comment: I actually don't think you can unfortunately. You can assign `malloc` to a memoryview with `<double[:size0,:size1:1]>malloc(...)` but it does seem to need the GIL. I don't like `**` arrays because they're non-contiguous, have a lot of extra allocation and deallocation (which is easy to get wrong), and take two steps to look up.  Unfortunately I don't think there's a great solution. I'd use `with gil:` blocks personally